# JMonkeyEngine display a spatial in a Nifty GUI interface

Tags: jmonkeyengine

I want to display a spatial (or the rendering of a spatial/scene) in my HUD interface. I'm really not sure how to go with this. I have search the documentation, but all the queries I search yields no result, and all I could find about images is that one can specify one with the `setBackgroundImage` method in the builder and `setImage` from the `ImageRenderer` class. The latter takes a `String` or a `NiftyImage`, but I'm not sure how to create one without loading an image file.

Any help to understand this (if even possible) is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is but one way I can imagin to get this working.

Creating a new `NiftyImage` as it is needed to get requires two arguments:

1. the `NiftyRenderEngine` you can receive from the current Nifty-GUI instance using the `getRenderEngine` function
2. A `RenderImage` that is part of the SPI.

The key is to implement the `RenderImage` yourself. To be more precise you have to overload `RenderImageJme` that is used by the JME-Renderer for Nifty to to define images. This class implements a `getTexture()` method you can overwrite to send in a alternative texture.

If you render the things you want to display to a texture and return this texture in your own implementation of the `RenderImageJme`, then you should be able to display what ever you want.

Comment: where is that implementation? `de.lessvoid.nifty.spi.render.RenderImage` is an interface and has only 3 methods : `getWidth()`, `getHeight()` and `dispose()`. Do you mean `com.jme3.niftygui.RenderImageJme` ?

Comment: Exactly. <code>com.jme3.niftygui.RenderImageJme</code> is the implementation of <code>de.lessvoid.nifty.spi.render.RenderImage</code> that is used by the render display JME uses. So you have to extend <code>RenderImageJme</code> in order to use it with the render device of JME. If you implement <code>RenderImage</code> and not <code>RenderImageJme</code> you wil receive a <code>ClassCastException</code> as the JME render device performs a unchecked cast.

Comment: then I suspect the magic happens here (`NiftyImage`) : `this.imageMode = ImageModeFactory.getSharedInstance().createImageMode(null, null);` where it returns a JME implementation of `ImageMode`?

Comment: I should. But as I just saw the `RenderImageJme` offers a constructor that should do what you want. Using `RenderImageJme(Texture2D)`. You need to get the graphics you want to display into this Texture2D using render-to-texture. The instance if the `RenderImageJme` can we wrapped into a `NiftyImage` using `new NiftyImage(nifty.getRenderEngine(), newRenderImageJme)`. That should do the job.

Comment: Forgot about this question! But this is what I ended up using and it works great! I made an utility class that received a root node and from which the camera could be controlled, and it allowed making UI views of the same scene from different angles (ex: rear view mirror in a race, bullet-time view on a missile, etc.) or display custom scenes (3D map, model, etc.) seemlessly. Got me good marks on my assignment.